# C# Winforms inherit usercontrol with objects and modify

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, user-controls

I've created my usercontrol called ucn with a datagridview that fills the usercontrol.

after I've created another usercontrol inherited from ucn:

```
public partial class ucnRequest : ucn
{
```

and in designmode i see the datagridview:

[image: usercontrol inherited]

is ok, but I can't add columns for example.

in the main usercontrol I changed the Modifiers property to public but nothing changes...

thanks

Comment: Did you also recompile after changing the modifier?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes, cleaned and rebuilt, but nothing changed

Comment: WPF, WinForms, jQuery ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry, winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because your `UserControl` will not by default act as a "container" control in the Windows Forms editor, so the Windows Forms editor will not expose its public properties.

To make it a "container" control in the Windows Forms editor you can add the following attribute to the class:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))] 
public class MyUserControl: System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
     ...
```

See here for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813450

Comment: thanks, but doesn't works, the usercontrol is ok, is the datagridview inside that causes problem

Comment: Did you apply the attribute to the `ucn` class?

Comment: yes, but in the designer of the child the menu to add columns is not present

Comment: @ghiboz did you ever manage to get this working?